# YouTube iframe api behavior on Chromecast

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, chromecast

Trying to get a YouTube video playing on Chromecast, not using the YouTube receiver but simply the iframe YouTube api. When the receiver url is loaded in a desktop chrome browser it plays ok but when the same url is loaded onto Chromecast I get the message 'This video is currently unavailable - Learn More'. If I keep trying to get the widget, once created, to play different videos it sometimes also says 'The Adobe Flash Player is required for video playback'.

The widget is created in the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() callback using new YT.Player as shown in the docs. Maybe I'm confused but I thought the iframe api was html5 based, not flash based. Has anyone successfully achieved this or is this unsupported on Chromecast, hence the weird behaviour? I also stumbled across this http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: I've successfully built a receiver that utilizes the iFrame API, and haven't had any problem with any video I've tried yet. What video IDs have given you errors, so I can try them out in my receiver and, if successful, share the code here as an answer?

Comment: Every single one I tried. For example, from the youtube api reference example - 'M7lc1UVf-VE'

Comment: But it's very encouraging that you have it working - probably just configuration/initialization. If you could post some code that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code I'm currently using on my receiver. The message handling (both directions) is hit and miss, and I'm currently working through that ... but the loading of the iFrame library, the embedding of the video, etc. all works. If it doesn't work on your end, we can start to investigate how your setup might be different. I've tried to add comments where it might be helpful.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // first create our receiver object and our channel handler
        var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver('{YOUR_APP_ID}', ['ChromecastYoutube'],"",5);
        var ytChannelHandler = new cast.receiver.ChannelHandler('ChromecastYoutube'); //  'using 'ChromecastYoutube' as my dev namespace. Wouldn't really be that in production.
        ytChannelHandler.addChannelFactory(receiver.createChannelFactory('ChromecastYoutube'));
        ytChannelHandler.addEventListener(
                cast.receiver.Channel.EventType.MESSAGE,
                onMessage.bind(this)
        );

        receiver.start();

        window.addEventListener('load', function() { // we won't try to load the iframe libraries until the chromecast window is fully loaded.
                var tag = document.createElement('script');
                tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        });

        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                        height: '562',
                        width: '1000',
                        videoId: 'jLlSqucqXB0',
                        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0 },
                        events: {
                                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                'onPlayerStateChange': onStateChange
                        }
                });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
                document.getElementById('annotation').innerHTML="We're ready to go";
        }

        function onStateChange(event) {
                switch (event.data) {
                        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
                                // TODO let sender know we're done, then close casting 
                                break;
                        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                                // TODO let sender know we're playing 
                                break;
                        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                                // TODO let sender know we're paused 
                                break;
                }
        }

        function onMessage(event) { // currently, any one of these will work, but subsequent ones seem to falter. Investigating...
                ytBindings={"playVideo":player.playVideo(),"pauseVideo":player.pauseVideo(),"stopVideo":player.stopVideo(),"getStatus":player.getPlayerState()}
                ytBindings[event.message];
        }


</script>
<style>
#wrapper {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        text-align: center;
}
#annotation {
        color: #ffffcc;
        font-size: 200%;
        margin-top:25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="annotation"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's similar to mine in every respect except one.I'd set up a SoundCloud widget first, also in an iframe, and then casually just added a YouTube iframe on the same page. Seems like they cannot coexist, but I have no idea why. If I remove the SoundCloud widget then the videos play fine. If you feel so inclined then add this...   <iframe id="sc-widget" 
      width="100%" height="170" 
      scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
      src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/97674171&auto_play=true&buying=false&liking=false&download=false&sharing=false">
   </iframe>

Comment: Seems it's more complicated and maybe nothing to do with the additional iframe. With just the YouTube iframe it worked for set of video ids I initially used, but I get the flash error now for any of the following ids.... ktvTqknDobU , 5NV6Rdv1a3I , e9SeJIgWRPk

Comment: Those are all Vevo videos. Unfortunately, Vevo (and some other content providers, often related to music) put in restrictions in their videos so that they can't be embedded at all, or can only be embedded in Flash players, etc. If there's a block in place preventing HTML5 embedding, it will attempt to default to the Flash embed (that's what the iFrame is for, of course), and this triggers the error because the Chromecast has no Flash player. If you try to force HTML5 mode, you get an error 150 indicating it can't be embedded.

Comment: As far as the Soundcloud widget goes, it's a strange issue. It plays fine on its own, but does throw a couple of DOM errors. When coupled with a YouTube iframe, the YouTube embed is throwing an error 5, which is a generic error in the HTML5 player (I wonder if that's being triggered by the errors the soundcloud widget is throwing).

Comment: Very helpful - thank you. I'll need to figure out non-embeddable videos on the client to avoid requesting. Regarding SoundCloud, I don't need both to co-exist but good to know there's a problem there.

Comment: This must be a Chromecast bug since the same videos play fine in iframes on Safari iPad. See this: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=126

Comment: Unfortunately can no longer edit my comment above... Google requested I file a bug with Youtube: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5923

Comment: Regarding knowing if a video is playable or not.
Make a server side call to:
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID&el=embedded

You'll get back a long string with various info, which will contain either "status=ok" if it can be played or "status=fail" if not. Unfortunately, this must be done from the server side due to CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Current behavior: it now seems to be fixed with Chromecast firmware 16041 and if the country code is set correctly during Chromecast setup. See the latest comment here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5923

Old answer:
Here is the root cause of the issue: https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/2995235?hl=en
*Some videos may not play using Chromecast. Private videos, live content, and videos not approved for mobile playback will not work with Chromecast.*
Hopefully this will change, kills a primary Chromecast use case.

Comment: Getting requests to try and figure this out.... I assumed Vevo videos wouldn't play on Chromecast because the are not embeddable. For the iframe youtube player this is certainly the case. However, the Android YouTube app can cast without issue (and without ads). Obviously Google can do things we can't, but do you think if i switch to using the YouTube receiver rather than the iframe widget this will solve the issue?

Comment: See the updated answer. Seems like Chromecast Youtube restrictions have been lifted.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue and found the cause to be the fact that I was using html5 audio to play some sound effects just before the video began. Removing the sound effects made the youtube player work again.