# Casting Youtube video to custom CAF receiver using IFrame approach

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am trying to create a custom receiver app, which can play youtube videos using Iframe approach.

I am not able to find documentation to link the YouTube player to  in the cast framework.

Note : I am using the CAF receiver framework.

Basically i want to link the Cast Receiver framework and the Youtube Iframe approach.

Any help would be really apprecaiated.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582694/youtube-iframe-api-behavior-on-chromecast). It has sample code of a receiver that utilizes the iFrame API. You may also check this [reported issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35174517) wherein it stated that it now seems to be fixed with Chromecast firmware 16041 and make sure that the country code is set correctly during Chromecast setup.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this with using the CAF receiver framework user2191908?

Comment: Did you find an answer?